# How to send notification by calling api from a Android background service in a seperate process periodically

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I want to send notification to the user by calling an API periodically to check if there is any pending notification whether the user is using the app or not. I want to run the service in background for 24 hours.

right now I am doing the task by Alarm Manager

here is the code :

***Service:***

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService { 

    public NotificationService() {

        super("NotificationService");

    }

    @Override

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) { 

        //call api

        sendNotification();

    } 
    private void sendNotification() {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Hello")
                        .setContentText("Hello World")
                        .setAutoCancel(true); 
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);  
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this); 
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        playNotificationSound();

    }
}
```

***Receiver***

```
public class NotificationServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);

        context.startService(dailyUpdater); 
    }
}
```

***AlarmManager***

```
private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {

        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); 
        Intent downloader = new Intent(context, NotificationServiceReceiver.class);
        downloader.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123546, downloader, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pendingIntent);


    }
```

The issue is that the alarm manager is not working sometimes, when I start the app again then its stats working.

Comment: Have you considered using push notifications from the server, instead of polling for notifications from the client?

Comment: Not yet.. We need to pull notification based on the user login credentials..

Comment: How you conform that your Alarm manager is not working?May be your receiver is not awake to run service.Please check this.

Comment: The interval is 15 minute. In-spite of there is a pending notification its not showing but as soon as I open the app its shows instantly.. @Rama

Comment: may be its the issue.Check it by debugging or placing  logs in receiver and in service.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `BroadcastReceiver` is guaranteed to run, but not the `Service` due to power save. You'll need to use a wake lock (see the docs on `WakefulReceiver`) to ensure your `Service` gets a chance to run. This article will help: http://hiqes.com/android-alarm-ins-outs/

Note that the new Doze mode will also affect this.

Comment: See the article.  :-)  It gives details about alarms and also has a github repo for the sample code.  The sample code starts an `Activity` rather than a `Service`, but the same principle applies.  It also uses a static wake lock at the `Application` level rather than using the wakeful receiver.  Both are valid, though Android Studio will complain that using a direct wakelock is deprecated (you can ignore that - it's frowned upon but ok to use.)

Comment: let the `NotificationServiceReceiver` extend a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and start the service like: `startWakefulService(context, dailyUpdater)`. Don't forget to release the wake lock by calling `NotificationServiceReceiver.completeWakefuIntent(intent)` (in the Service class) when the work is done.